# How to prove the existence of such a non-zero operator

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am self studying  a 2nd course in Functional Analysis using Functional analysis by Rudin and a set of exercises.

I was not able to solve this particular problem and I need help.

> Question: Let H be a Hilbert space of dimension $\geq 2$. Show that there exists a non -zero operator $T\in L(H)$ st $\langle Tx,x\rangle  =0   $ for every $x\in H$.

On the converse, let if there exists  $ T\in L(H)$ such that $\langle Tx,x\rangle =0$ for every $x\in H$ then $T \equiv 0$.

But what can be contradiction here?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not looking at Rudin right now, but the difference is whether you consider a real or a complex Hilbert space.

In a real space, you use the idea that the matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$ satisfies $\langle Ax,x\rangle=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R^2$. So, given an orthonormal basis $\{e_n\}$, define $T$ as the linear operator that does
$$
Te_1=e_2,\qquad Te_2=-e_1,\qquad Te_{k+2}=0,\qquad\qquad k\in\mathbb N. 
$$
Then, for any $x$
$$
\langle Tx,x\rangle=x_2x_1-x_1x_2=0.
$$
In a complex Hilbert space, the above doesn't work. If $\langle Tx,x\rangle=0$ for all $x$, then $\langle Tx,y\rangle=0$ for all $x,y$ by polarization, and so $T=0$.

---

**Edit:** the Polarization Identity is the equality
$$\tag1
\langle Tx,y\rangle=\frac14\,\sum_{k=0}^3i^k\langle T(x+i^ky),x+i^k y\rangle. 
$$

Comment: In the real case every skew symmetric matrix will do.

Comment: @Martin How does <Tx,x>=0 , then <Tx,y>=0 using polarization? What is polarization? How to use it here? can you please elaborate?

Comment: @Martin How does matrix A satisfies <Ax,x> ? Can you please show your work?

Comment: @Martin can you please reply to the comments above?

Comment: Not sure what's unanswered. You don't know how to see a matrix as a linear operator, and how to calculate the inner product in $\mathbb R^2$? That's what you are asking?

Comment: @MartinArgerami I am not able to understand how should I calculate inner product in $\mathbb{R}^2$? Can you please help me with it? I really want to understand this question.

Comment: In the real case, $$\Big\langle\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}z\\ w\end{bmatrix}\Big\rangle=xz+yw.$$ In the complex case, $$\Big\langle\begin{bmatrix}x\\ y\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}z\\ w\end{bmatrix}\Big\rangle=x\overline z+y\overline w.$$ I would say that if you are struggling with basic facts about inner products in the finite-dimensional case, you might consider whether you are ready to learn about operators.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

[On a complex preHilbert space, you are right](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/777587): if for all vectors $v\in H$, $\langle Tv,v\rangle=0,$ then $T=0.$

But on a real Hilbert space of dimension $\ge2$, take a $\pi/2$-rotation on some plane $P$, and complete by $0$ on $P^\perp.$